# Using pyodbc in Unit Tests

Tags: python, sql-server-2008, unit-testing, python-2.6, pyodbc

I'm struggling to write unit tests for Python that use Pyodbc to query a local SQL Server database.

The following code runs...

```
import pyodbc
import random
import unittest
from EmailSender import EmailSender

class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.email_sender = EmailSender()
        self.other_email_sender = EmailSender()

    def test_for_initialisation_variables(self):
        """
        Tests to check that the object is created properly
        """
        self.assertTrue(self.email_sender.server)
        self.assertTrue(self.email_sender.errorLogFile)
        self.assertTrue(self.email_sender.connection)
        self.assertTrue(self.email_sender.cursor)
        self.assertTrue(self.email_sender.siteAuth)
        self.assertTrue(self.email_sender.apiCallsLimitPerRun)

    def test_SQL_Server_Connection(self):
        for value in self.email_sender.cursor.execute("select * from sys.tables"):.
            print value
```

However, when I add a second, almost identical test to the code...

```
import pyodbc
import random
import unittest
from EmailSender import EmailSender

class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.email_sender = EmailSender()
        self.other_email_sender = EmailSender()

    def test_for_initialisation_variables(self):
        """
        Tests to check that the object is created properly
        """
        self.assertTrue(self.email_sender.server)
        self.assertTrue(self.email_sender.errorLogFile)
        self.assertTrue(self.email_sender.connection)
        self.assertTrue(self.email_sender.cursor)
        self.assertTrue(self.email_sender.siteAuth)
        self.assertTrue(self.email_sender.apiCallsLimitPerRun)

    def test_SQL_Server_Connection(self):
        for value in self.email_sender.cursor.execute("select * from sys.tables"):.
            print value

    def test_getSites_method(self):
        for value in self.other_email_sender.cursor.execute("select * from sys.tables"):.
            print value
```

The third test fails with the following error message:

`Error: ('IM001', '[IM001] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver does not support this function (0) (SQLRowCount)')`

p.s.

Just to note, I started off with just one email_sender object being created but couldn't run back to back queries so then changed the query to be identical and when that didn't work, added another connection and cursor so there could be no issues re: the position with the cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution - basically the problem was in the (default) tearDown method.

Something was going on so the cursor wasn't being reset - I overrode that method with the below and hey presto, it worked:

```
def tearDown(self):
    """
    Make sure we reset the cursor
    """
    if self.email_sender.connection:
        self.email_sender.connection.close()
    del self.email_sender
```